# Run Ruby program until error

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to make a Ruby program keep executing until the program has an error? I want my loop to stop when the program returns an error.
Thanks

Comment: You should state the error's form, for example, an exception or a 'false' returning. As they'll have different handling methods. For a infinite loop, i suppose the Kernel#loop would be better than 'while true'.

Answer (score 2):

A infinite loop can help?

```
while true do
    your code
end
```

If your code throw an error the loop stops.

Comment: Interesting... I just looked it up and the `do` is optional. I don't think I've ever seen it there before.

Answer (score 2):

This is another example. Will run infinite times till exception comes and also handles your exception and then exit form code.

```
inc = 5
while true do
  begin
puts 4/inc
inc-=1
  rescue Exception=> e
    puts e
    exit
  end
end
```